# Stopping the explorer.exe taskbar from opening when using the windows file explorer on XP

Tags: c++, windows-xp, registry, explorer, windows-shell

I am creating a shell-replacement for developers, which creates a new windows user, titled "developer" and only when you log into this user, should the shell be launched.

The replacement start menu is replaced with a shell based terminal with great features, the taskbar is replaces with a tree based view for windows, and the process monitor is replaced with a view where you can attach process monitors, debuggers, profiles, and memory leak detectors, etc.

I would like my application replace the regular windows shell. I have however came across a registry key that, on windows 7, works just fine. but on windows XP if I use the regular windows XP file manager the windows XP task bar from explorer.exe launches, even though I changed said registry entry!

Does anybody have any idea what it is I need to do to fully replace the windows shell AND taskbar using windows XP while still retaining use of the windows based file manager?: )

Edit:

Using C++, developing using NetBeans using Qt for my gui library. however, as I do not think this should effect the answer, I figured I would include it either way.

Comment: If all else fails, you could probably just hide it. Of course that's outdone by any real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Windows XP does not support per-user shell replacement (not sure, it's been a while since I played with the desktop stuff), but you should be able to set the 'Shell' entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and prevent Explorer from registering itself as the shell when it first runs. This will affect all the users in the machine, of course.

Comment: well i was going to write a kind of bootstrap where it detects the user and boots explorer.exe if it is not the "developer" user. on another note, that is the registry entry which i noted that i am currently using the set the shell already - 

the problem is that it works, until explorer.exe is launched for file management. when we do this, the task bar comes back and it assumed the role of shell agian, when we are just trying to pass the executable file system path arguments for using the native file manager. any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: reason being is that closing the process would destroy the file manager as well...

Comment: found a custom solution, may have just been my development machine's antivirus, or something else unknown. answer accepted.